# How to print only a certain column of DataFrame in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

Can one use the actions `collect` or `take` to print only a given column of DataFrame?

This

```
df.col.collect()
```

gives error

> TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

and this:

```
df[df.col].take(2)
```

gives

> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"filter expression 'col' of type string is not a boolean.;"

Comment: does `df['col'].collect()` work or `df['col'].take(2)` work?

Comment: @EdChum No, it leads to the same error as my first attempt

Answer (score 69, accepted):

`select` and `show`:

```
df.select("col").show()
```

or `select`, `flatMap`, `collect`:

```
df.select("col").rdd.flatMap(list).collect()
```

Bracket notation (`df[df.col]`) is used only for logical slicing and columns by itself (`df.col`) are not distributed data structures but SQL expressions and cannot be collected.